# CSOM, How to prevent duplicate error when create new list item with a unique enforce column value?

Tags: csom, splistitem, spfield, unique

I have a list with 2 columns. These columns have "enforce unique values" enabled. I would like to add a new list item in CSOM. But got sometimes the duplicate error. How can I prevent this error? What is the best practice to check if the field value already exist?

```
// create new list item
           var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

            using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    var list = clientContext.Web.GetListByUrl("Lists/Perioden");

                    var itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                    var listItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
                    listItem["Title"] = titel;
                    listItem["Van"] = vanaf; // this field needs unique value
                    listItem["TM"] = tM; // this field needs unique value


                    listItem.Update();
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CamlQuery` to check if there are any items with a specific field value. An example below:

```
SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = String.Format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Van'/>
                <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>","vanaf");
            ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

            clientContext.Load(collListItem);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

You can check the `count` property of `collListItem` to decide how to proceed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534956(v=office.14).aspx